# ¿Cómo Actualizar una propiedad data en Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy haciendo un input "reactivo" en Vue como el del tutorial de su pagina web (este es el código del tutorial) :

```js
var app6 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-6',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app-6">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
</div>
```

Pero con la diferencia de que quiero que en el `<p>` aparezca primero un texto predefinido, y luego cuando el usuario escriba en el input que este texto aparezca en el `<p>`.
 La diferencia con lo del tutorial es que en el tutorial el `<input>` ya aparece escrito lo mismo que en el `<p>`, yo quiero que en el `<input>` no este escrito nada hasta que el usuario quiera escribir algo.

Este es mi código, ahora mismo el `<h1>` no se actualiza según el usuario escribe en el input:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      message: "Name your Todo",
      message_2: "",
    }
})
```

```html
 <div id="app" class="presentation-container">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <div>
      <input v-model="message_2" />
      <button id="newT-tbn">New To-Do List</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Entonces había pensado en hacer:

```
data.message = data.message_2;
```

Para que se actualize el `h1` con lo que el `message_2` se convierte después de que el usuario escriba.

Pero no funciona. ¿Algo similar que se pueda hacer para lograr esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar `v-if` con esto muestras el control solo si cumple la condición.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     message: "texto predefinido",
      message_2: "",
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="presentation-container">
    <h1 v-if="message_2 === ''">{{ message }}</h1>
    <h1 v-if="message_2 !== ''">{{ message_2 }}</h1>
    <div>
      <input v-model="message_2" />
      <button id="newT-tbn">New To-Do List</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar una [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) dentro de tu tag `h1`, que mientras el `v-model` del `input` que está bindeado con la propiedad `inputMessage` sea `===` a `""` te muestre el valor de la propiedad `defaultMessage` que es `"Name your Todo"` caso contrario te muestre el valor del v-model de la propiedad `inputMessage`, como a continuación:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      defaultMessage: "Name your Todo",
      inputMessage: "",
    },
    computed: {
      finalMessage() {
        return this.inputMessage === "" ? this.defaultMessage : this.inputMessage
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="presentation-container">
  <h1>{{ finalMessage }}</h1>
  <div>
    <input v-model="inputMessage" />
    <button id="newT-tbn">New To-Do List</button>
  </div>
</div>
```